# Upload video with custom thumbnail to Facebook throug Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, upload, video-thumbnails

I am currently developing an ASP.NET MVC application which uploads videos for a Facebook User to Facebook through Graph API. Video uploading to "/{user-id}/videos" path works correctly, but when I try to upload a video with a custom thumbnail by adding "thumb" parameter to video parameters (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/videos/):

```
dynamic videoParameters = new ExpandoObject();
videoParameters.source = new FacebookMediaObject()
{
    ContentType = video.ContentType,
    FileName = video.FileName,
}.SetValue(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(video.FilePath));

if (thumbnail != null)
{
    videoParameters.thumb = thumbnail;
}

dynamic result = this.FacebookClient.Post("/me/videos", videoParameters);

return result;
```

an exception is thrown:

(OAuthException - #100) (#100) Invalid image format. It should be an image 
file data.
at Facebook.FacebookClient.ProcessResponse(HttpHelper httpHelper, String 
responseString, Type resultType, Boolean containsEtag, IList`1 batchEtags)
at Facebook.FacebookClient.Api(HttpMethod httpMethod, String path, Object parameters, Type resultType)
at Facebook.FacebookClient.Post(String path, Object parameters)
at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2) ...

I have already tried to pass the thumbnail variable to "videoParameters.thumb" parameter as a Bitmap file and a base64 string. Since in documentation is written: "The video thumbnail raw data to be uploaded and associated with a video.", I have also passed the thumbnail as a byte array. But in all these cases the above mentioned exception is thrown.

After long research I still have not found solution of this problem. Does someone know what is the solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, did you solve this? I have similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

What i ended up doing (in the .NET SDK vs FB API v2.12) was the same thing as the video upload - I put a FacebookMediaStream (i assume FacebookMediaObject would work too) in the thumb property with ContentType of "image/png" and Filename of anything really ("Thumb.png"?).

There should be a similar approach in other languages/SDKs, just follow the same process you used to upload the actual video content.

This went through and i saw the thumbnail as the default one for the video in the Video Library when looking at my page.